# How to use controllers as services configuring the routing in yaml without annotations

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

So far I've been using annotations for my routes but for a new project I'd to start using yaml routes instead.

The problem is I don't know how to use controllers as services by doing that. I have my controller:

```
final class SuspendController extends Controller
{

    /** @var UserManagerInterface */
    private $userManager;

    public function __construct(
        UserManagerInterface $userManager    
    ) {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return Response
     */
    public function suspendAction() : Response
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $user->setStatus(User::STATUS_SUSPENDED);

        $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_logout');
    }
}
```

My routing.yml:

```
suspend_session:
    path:      /suspend
    defaults:  { _controller: UserBundle:Suspend:suspend }
```

And I include the following services definition:

```
services:

  controller.suspend_account:
      class: UserBundle\Controller\SuspendController
      arguments:
          - '@fos_user.user_manager'
```

The problem is that the fos_user_manager never gets injected in the controller. Is there any annotation that I should include in the routing to specify that that controller is a service (something equivalent to the @Route service annotation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you user the Controller as a Service, you can't use the helper method `getUser` of the base class because you haven't yet the container injected.
For redirect Route you need the router dependencies also.

So you should inject all the necessary dependency (also the token manager) and dial with them.

```
  controller.suspend_account:
      class: UserBundle\Controller\SuspendController
      arguments:
          - '@fos_user.user_manager'
          - '@router'
          - '@security.token_storage'
```

Then your implementation looks like this:

```
/**
 * @return Response
 */
public function suspendAction() : Response
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->securityTokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

    $user->setStatus(User::STATUS_SUSPENDED);

    $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

    return $this->redirect($this->router->generate('fos_user_security_logout'), 200);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Then define the route as follow:

```
suspend_session:
    path:      /suspend
    defaults:  { _controller: controller.suspend_account:suspendAction  }
```

As described in the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html#referring-to-the-service).

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @Matteo, I think you can still define a controller as a service even if extends the controller. The problem that I have is the services are not injected to the construct method

Comment: hi @petekaner check my update, probably the route definition is wrong

Comment: Don't forget to add the Action suffix.  controller.suspend_account:suspendAction http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html#referring-to-the-service  And you can use the base controller functionality if you add calls: [setContainer,        ['@service_container']] to the service definition.  Just be sure you understand why it is needed or you will end up chasing your tail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your routing to include the full controller function.
E.g.

```
suspend_session:
    path:      /suspend
    defaults:  { _controller: UserBundle:Suspend:suspendAction }
```

Comment: I still get the same error Type error: Too few arguments to function UserBundle\Controller\SuspendController::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/vagrant/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php on line 202 and exactly 1 expected